# Does $\gamma$ closed in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0 \}$ imply that $\gamma$ is piece-wise differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0 \}$.

I want to calculate $$\omega(\gamma,0):=\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac 1 {z-z_0} dz$$

As far as I know this number is only defined for $\gamma$ piece-wise differentiable and closed ?

How do I see that $\gamma$ must be piece-wise differentiable ? Is it implicitly assumed ? It is only stated to be closed.

Comment: Probably there is a global assumption that all considered curves shall be piecewise $C^1$. One can define integrals over rectifiable curves, and in the case of analytic (on a neighbourhood of the trace of the curve) integrands, also for more general curves, but that is rarely done.

Comment: Sometimes the definition (for analytic integrands) is extended to continuous curves: Any such curve can be approximated by a differentiable curve such that the integrand is analytic in the region between the curves.  The the value of the integral obtained does not depend on which approximation you use.

Comment: But I cannot use $\gamma$ as my approximation then ?